# docker: Error response from daemon: network mongo-network not found

Tags: docker, docker-container

I am trying to create a container in a network but while creating I am getting this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: network mongo-network not found
```

Here `mongo-network` is the name of network which i have created. The command I am using is:

```
docker run --network mongo-network -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name mongodb -d mongo
```

Error in this command or something else happens. How to slove this problem?

Comment: `How to slove this problem?` Create mongo-network network. Or remove the option.

Comment: Can you run `docker network ls` and add the output here?

Answer (score 0):

Raj use `$docker` network ls to see the available networks. Use the name of the network created or present in place of `mongo-network`. If you wanna use the same network name, you first need to create a network by the name `mongo-network` you can use the following command:

```bash
$docker network create -d bridge mongo-network
```

If you use the default network name it would be something like this.

```bash
$docker run --network none -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name mongodb -d mongo
```

Or else you can execute your command and wont be having an error.